# LWC/Jest/PapaParse: How to ensure mocked function can call private function?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-jest

thanks in advance for any help!

I'm currently trying to write a test for the following behavior:  the User uploads a .csv file to a lightning-input element of my LWC, and an HTML element of the component updates to display the row count of the .csv.  The parsing of the .csv is done through a third-party js library, Papa Parser.  However, I'm running into a number of issues trying to test this.

1. The Papa Parser function ('parse') hits an error "parse is not a function" when called by my change handler during the test.  So, fair enough, I've written a mock for the function.  However:
2. The "magic" of the parse() function is defined in a property ('step') of a 'config' object passed to parse().  The value of 'step' is a function that handles the logic for what to do with each row of the .csv as parse() streams it, so here's where I'm hitting my roadblock.

The output of this (private) function ('countRows') increments the component's (private) row counter, which is the behavior I'm trying to test.  Since it's private, when I try to explicitly call it in my mocked 'parse' function, I get an error that it's not a function.  Note:  if I make the function public, all tests run as expected, and the functionality in-org also behaves appropriately.

I've tried everything I can think of to not have to mock the 'parse' function, but haven't gotten anything to work.  Am I going about this the right way / is there something fundamental I'm missing?  Any help would be appreciated!

**parserApp.test.js**

```
import ParserApp from "c/parserApp";
import { loadScript } from "lightning/platformResourceLoader";

...

window.Papa = jest.mock(
  "lightning/platformResourceLoader",
  () => {
    return {
      loadScript() {
        return new Promise((resolve) => {
          global.Papa = require("../../../staticresources/PapaParse");
          resolve();
        });
      }
    };
  },
  { virtual: true }
);

describe("c-parser-app", () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    element = createElement("c-parser-app", {
      is: ParserApp
    });
  });
  afterEach(() => {
    while (document.body.firstChild) {
      document.body.removeChild(document.body.firstChild);
    }
    jest.clearAllMocks();
  });

...

  it("calls the parseCSV method when file is uploaded", () => {
    //Arrange
    const spyPreview = jest.spyOn(element, "countRows");
    window.Papa.parse = jest.fn().mockImplementation((csv) => {
      [...csv].forEach((row) => {
        spyPreview(row);
      });
    });

    //Act

    document.body.appendChild(element);
    const fileInput = element.shadowRoot.querySelector(".file-input-component");
    const rowCount = element.shadowRoot.querySelector(".row-count-display");

    fileInput.dispatchEvent(
      new CustomEvent("change", {
        detail: {
          files: [mockCSV]
        }
      })
    );

    //Assert
    return Promise.resolve().then(() => {
      expect(window.Papa.parse).toBeCalledTimes(1);
      expect(window.Papa.parse.mock.calls[0][0]).toBe(mockCSV);
      const displayedRowCount = parseInt(
        rowCount.textContent.replace(/[^0-9]*/, ""),
        10
      );
      expect(displayedRowCount).toBe(mockCSV.length);
    });
  });
});
```

**parserApp.js**

```
import { loadScript } from "lightning/platformResourceLoader";
import PARSER from "@salesforce/resourceUrl/PapaParse";

export default class ParserApp extends LightningElement {
  _rowCount = 0;
  _errorCount = 0;
  file;

  @api get errorCount() {
    return this._errorCount;
  }
  @api get rowCount() {
    return this._rowCount;
  }
  connectedCallback() {
    loadScript(this, PARSER);
  }

  @api // <---this is the decorator I'd like to remove to turn the function private
  countRows = (result) => {
    this._rowCount++;
  };

  // the lightning-input element's change handler:
  countCSVRows(event) {
    const file = event.detail.files[0];
    this._rowcount = 0;
    this._errorCount = 0;
    this.file = file;
    Papa.parse(file, {
      delimiter: "", // auto-detect
      newline: "", // auto-detect
      quoteChar: '"',
      preview: 10,
      step: (result) => {
        this.countRows(result);
      },
      skipEmptyLines: true
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Jest can only access the component API so private functions cannot be directly tested or mocked. You have to perform indirect testing.

Comment: Hi @PhilW, thanks for commenting!  I'm aware that I can't directly access private functions -- my preference would of course be to test dispatching a change event, letting my code run, and check that the text displayed to the user is what I expect when it comes out the other side.

However, the third-party library throws an error when called by my LWC during the test, so I've had to mock it, meaning I now have to find a way to make it call the functions it calls in my LWC to present the displayed values to the user.

Do you have any advice for how this can be tested indirectly?

Comment: Hi, I am also considering PapaParse in an LWC to parse large CSV files. Have you had luck using it in an LWC?

Comment: @skycafe, yes, it's a pretty handy utility and works in an LWC.  I'm working now on a way to make it handle large files (the examples I've seen using it in an LWC don't take advantage of its workers or streaming functionality, and just stores everything in browser memory, so the browser crashes at scale).  I still haven't found a way to build jest tests for it, though, unfortunately.

Comment: Hi CurtD, thanks. I got it working but stored entire parsed file in memory as you said. Then uploading a chunk at a time.  Not jesting, nor using workers, but tested and checked payload size and apex heap to identify ideal chunk size for this use case. I found parse is blazingly fast but since I am processing multiple files at once, care has to be made with the async nature of parse to only parse one file at a time then upload it. Sorry not more help.